# non negativity of Fourier coefficients of modular forms

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, modular-forms

I would like to know if there exists some criteria to test whether a given modular form, of level N with integral or half-integral weight, has non negative coefficients. I am also interested in results saying when certain coefficients are necessarily non negative.

Any research paper or reference is welcome !

Comment: (Cute user-name... :)

Answer (score 3):

Any cusp form will have infinitely many positive coefficients and infinitely many negative coefficients. This is pointed out in [the answer from reuns](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4531726/9754) when the multiplier system is trivial and there is trivial central character.

For holomorphic cuspidal Hecke eigenforms of integer weight $k \geq 2$, this result is also implied by the Sato-Tate distributions of (normalized) coefficients. This is a much, much stronger result than what you ask for.

More generally, fix some half-plane passing through the origin. Any cusp form, with any weight and any character, will have infinitely many coefficients inside each half-plane. This follows from the pair of facts that
$$ \sum_{n \leq X} a(n) = o(X) $$
and
$$ \sum_{n \leq X} \lvert a(n) \rvert^2 \asymp X. $$
Here, the coefficients $a(n)$ are normalized to be $1$ on average. The first is the analogue of the circle problem in this case, and the second is essentially work due to Rankin and Selberg (separately). This applies also to half-integral weight forms.

The same is not necessarily true of non-cuspidal forms. For example, the classical theta function
$$ \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} e^{2 \pi i n^2 z} $$
is a modular form of weight $1/2$ with nonnegative coefficients. More generally, to any positive semidefinite quadratic form, one can associate a theta function with nonnegative coefficients.

I do not see an easy way to determine if a generic given modular form will have nonnegative coefficients if it is not cuspidal.

Comment: great answer ! I think the "easiest" way (for a form with real coefficients)  would be to split the coefficient of the given form into the eisenstein part (for which we know how to explicitly compute the coefficients) and the cusp form part. Then if the form is of integral weight, one can construct a procedure using Deligne's bound for the cusp form coefficients. If the form has half-integral weights, then we can use a variant of Basmaji's algorithm to compute a bases for the space of cusp forms using modular forms of integral weight.

Comment: I will soon post a solution of the procedure I constructed.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f\in S_k(\Gamma(N))$, ie. $f(z)=\sum_{n\ge 1} a_n e^{2i\pi nz}$ vanishes at all the cusps.

Then $ f(-1/z)z^{-k}=O(e^{-2\pi\Im(z)})$ as $\Im(z)\to \infty$ automatically implies that the $a_n$ aren't non-negative.

Comment: You are greatly confusing me... Did you say what you intended? Please explain further.

Comment: I don't think there is anything confusing, if the $a_n$ are non-negative then $\lim_{y\to 0} f(iy)=\sum_{n\ge 1} a_n > 0$

Comment: Maybe I'm over-tired... but isn't the limit of $ce^{-y}$ $0$ as $y\to+\infty$ for any (finite) constant $c$?

Comment: @paulgarrett reuns is taking $y \to 0$, not $y \to +\infty$. It is not clear to me why that limit must vanish because $f$ is a cusp form though... that's only the case if there happens to be a cusp at $z = 0$?

Comment: @prets, ah, oops, thanks for pointing out the $y\to 0^+$ rather than $+\infty$! :)

Comment: "... the $a_n$ aren't nonnegative" -- unless $f = 0$. :)

Comment: @prets There is a cusp at every rational. Being continuous at a cusp $a/b$ is defined in a slightly strange way: $\lim_{\Im(z)\to +\infty}f(\gamma(z))$ must converge when $\gamma\in SL_2(\Bbb{Z}),\gamma(\infty)=a/b$

Comment: Sorry of course I meant $\lim_{\Im(z)\to +\infty}f(\gamma(z)) \gamma'(z)^{k/2}$ must converge